# Get user's location (latitude, longitude) when visited

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, geolocation, geocoding

Whenever a user enters my site, i want to get his longitude, latitude to further use in my google maps. I have tried using HTML5 geolocation script and `geocoder gem`.

Using Geocoder gem, my hash is empty when trying below code, why is this happening ? Is this because i am running it in localhost ? Please suggest how to get it done if any other way.

I just need latitude and longitude of my user, thats it.

```
location = request.location
longitude = location.data['longitude']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you had carefully read documentation of geocoder gem you would notice that:

> Note that these methods will usually return nil in your test and
>   development environments because things like "localhost" and "0.0.0.0"
>   are not an Internet IP addresses.

Comment: any idea on how  to make it work in development mode for testing purposes ? i have tried few hacks but none work.